# Write a program that produces images of Christmas trees as output. I don't know what the error is

Tags: java

My code is resulting in an infinite loop when i run it. Don't know whats wrong.
!(https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F1aa%2F1aa1af9f-41ff-48d8-89e9-7b093a909045%2Fphpbrt5Fy.png)

I have tried the code below. It compiles properly.

public class Project3_1 {

```
//declare SEGMENTS and HEIGHT
public static final int SEGMENTS = 4;
public static final int HEIGHT = 4;
public static final int TOTAL = (2*(SEGMENTS)) + (2*(HEIGHT)) - 3;

public static void TopTree(int SEGMENTS, int HEIGHT) {


    for (int s = 1; s <= SEGMENTS; s++) {

        for (int h = 1; h <= HEIGHT; h++) {

            int ASTERISKS = ((2*s) + (2*h) - 3);
            int SPACES = ((TOTAL - ASTERISKS)/2);

            //spaces
            for (int b = 1; b <= SPACES; b++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Asterisks
            for (int a = 1; a <= ASTERISKS; a++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}

public static void TreeBase() {

    int x = (TOTAL - 7)/2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= (TOTAL-1)/2; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");

    for (int i = 1; i <= (TOTAL-1)/2; i++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("*");

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; x++){
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= (TOTAL - (x + 7)); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    TopTree(SEGMENTS, HEIGHT);
    TreeBase();
}
```

}

Comment: Here `for (int i = 1; i <= x; x++)` you're incrementing `x` instead of `i`. That means the loop will go on and on until `x` overflows.

Comment: khelwood is correct. It would be wise to learn how to use the debugger to step through your program, it can save you a lot of time and help to reduce the frustration of issues like this. That is how I solved it, and may be how he solved it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your third for loop in TreeBase(), you increment the wrong variable. The code you posted runs fine for me, it just doesn't make that bottom line of asterisks due to that loop I mentioned not being correct. Once you fix that, you should be good